# Card Carousel buttons are triggering other carousel card buttons

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

So I'm trying to have multiple Card Carousels, But when I click the second card carousel button, The first one moves but the second one doesn't, Same is the case with multiple, For example if i have 4 card carousels but only 1 works or moves, when i try to click the carousel next or previous buttons, only the first carousel moves.

code for two card carousels

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.pingendo.com/bootstrap/bootstrap-4.3.1.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@600&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<section class="pt-5 pb-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h3 class="mb-3">Carousel cards title </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-right">
            <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3 mr-1" href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3 " href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532781914607-2031eca2f00d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=7c625ea379640da3ef2e24f20df7ce8d">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517760444937-f6397edcbbcd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=42b2d9ae6feb9c4ff98b9133addfb698">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532712938310-34cb3982ef74?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3d2e8a2039c06dd26db977fe6ac6186a">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532771098148-525cefe10c23?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3f317c1f7a16116dec454fbc267dd8e4">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532715088550-62f09305f765?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=ebadb044b374504ef8e81bdec4d0e840">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506197603052-3cc9c3a201bd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=0754ab085804ae8a3b562548e6b4aa2e">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=ee8417f0ea2a50d53a12665820b54e23">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532777946373-b6783242f211?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=8ac55cf3a68785643998730839663129">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532763303805-529d595877c5?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=5ee4fd5d19b40f93eadb21871757eda6">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
<section class="pt-5 pb-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h3 class="mb-3">Carousel cards title </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-right">
            <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3 mr-1" href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3 " href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532781914607-2031eca2f00d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=7c625ea379640da3ef2e24f20df7ce8d">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517760444937-f6397edcbbcd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=42b2d9ae6feb9c4ff98b9133addfb698">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532712938310-34cb3982ef74?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3d2e8a2039c06dd26db977fe6ac6186a">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532771098148-525cefe10c23?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3f317c1f7a16116dec454fbc267dd8e4">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532715088550-62f09305f765?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=ebadb044b374504ef8e81bdec4d0e840">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506197603052-3cc9c3a201bd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=0754ab085804ae8a3b562548e6b4aa2e">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=ee8417f0ea2a50d53a12665820b54e23">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532777946373-b6783242f211?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=8ac55cf3a68785643998730839663129">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532763303805-529d595877c5?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=5ee4fd5d19b40f93eadb21871757eda6">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

code for only one

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.pingendo.com/bootstrap/bootstrap-4.3.1.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@600&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<section class="pt-5 pb-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h3 class="mb-3">Carousel cards title </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-right">
            <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3 mr-1" href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3 " href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532781914607-2031eca2f00d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=7c625ea379640da3ef2e24f20df7ce8d">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517760444937-f6397edcbbcd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=42b2d9ae6feb9c4ff98b9133addfb698">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532712938310-34cb3982ef74?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3d2e8a2039c06dd26db977fe6ac6186a">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532771098148-525cefe10c23?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3f317c1f7a16116dec454fbc267dd8e4">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532715088550-62f09305f765?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=ebadb044b374504ef8e81bdec4d0e840">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506197603052-3cc9c3a201bd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=0754ab085804ae8a3b562548e6b4aa2e">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=ee8417f0ea2a50d53a12665820b54e23">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532777946373-b6783242f211?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=8ac55cf3a68785643998730839663129">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532763303805-529d595877c5?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=5ee4fd5d19b40f93eadb21871757eda6">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: have a look at your ids. carouselExampleIndicators2 is the id for both. if you change it for second one (and inside the links) it will work fine

Answer (score 1):

You are using same ID for both carusels (`carouselExampleIndicators2`), so your buttons are triggering the first one. By changing the ID of the second one it will work just fine.

In my example i change the ID of the second one to `carouselExampleIndicators3`

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.pingendo.com/bootstrap/bootstrap-4.3.1.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@600&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<section class="pt-5 pb-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h3 class="mb-3">Carousel cards title </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-right">
            <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3 mr-1" href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3 " href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532781914607-2031eca2f00d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=7c625ea379640da3ef2e24f20df7ce8d">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517760444937-f6397edcbbcd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=42b2d9ae6feb9c4ff98b9133addfb698">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532712938310-34cb3982ef74?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3d2e8a2039c06dd26db977fe6ac6186a">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532771098148-525cefe10c23?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3f317c1f7a16116dec454fbc267dd8e4">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532715088550-62f09305f765?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=ebadb044b374504ef8e81bdec4d0e840">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506197603052-3cc9c3a201bd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=0754ab085804ae8a3b562548e6b4aa2e">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=ee8417f0ea2a50d53a12665820b54e23">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532777946373-b6783242f211?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=8ac55cf3a68785643998730839663129">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532763303805-529d595877c5?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=5ee4fd5d19b40f93eadb21871757eda6">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
<section class="pt-5 pb-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h3 class="mb-3">Carousel cards title </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-right">
            <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3 mr-1" href="#carouselExampleIndicators3" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3 " href="#carouselExampleIndicators3" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators3" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532781914607-2031eca2f00d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=7c625ea379640da3ef2e24f20df7ce8d">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517760444937-f6397edcbbcd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=42b2d9ae6feb9c4ff98b9133addfb698">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532712938310-34cb3982ef74?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3d2e8a2039c06dd26db977fe6ac6186a">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532771098148-525cefe10c23?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3f317c1f7a16116dec454fbc267dd8e4">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532715088550-62f09305f765?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=ebadb044b374504ef8e81bdec4d0e840">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506197603052-3cc9c3a201bd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=0754ab085804ae8a3b562548e6b4aa2e">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=ee8417f0ea2a50d53a12665820b54e23">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532777946373-b6783242f211?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=8ac55cf3a68785643998730839663129">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532763303805-529d595877c5?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=5ee4fd5d19b40f93eadb21871757eda6">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```